# Reading global environment from within a function in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

I need to access (i.e., read and save) the items of the environment I'm working in. I have written the following function to save all objects in my (global) environment:

```r
save_vars <- function(list.of.vars = NULL,
                      prefix = "StatusQuo",
                      path = "data") {
  if(is.null(list.of.vars)) list.of.vars <- ls()
  date_time <- Sys.time()
  if (!is.null(path))
    path <- paste0(path, "/")
  file_name <- paste0(path, prefix, "_", date_time, ".RData")
  save(list = list.of.vars, file = file_name)
}
```

The idea was that if no `list.of.vars` argument is passed to the function, using `ls()`, the function accesses the variables of the environment calling `save_vars`. However, it only saves the variables within the scope of the function itself. I know I can call the function as `save_vars(ls())` to do the job, but is there a neater way around it?

Comment: This should do the trick: `ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Thanks. G. Grothendieck proposed a way (passing `parent.frame()` as an argument) that the function can get the parent environment (not limited to the global env.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably cleanest to pass the environment:

```
fun <- function(envir = parent.frame()) ls(envir = envir)
fun()
```

This lists the objects in the caller but also lets the user change which environment is used.  For example, they could force the global environment to be used:

```
fun(.GlobalEnv)
```